# Ubuntu 16.04 some keys printing wrong

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

After logging into system (Ubuntu 16.04) with user. Some keys are printing wrong. When key 'o' is pressed it prints out '6', on pressing key 'm' it prints '0'  and on pressing key 'l' it prints '3'.

Before logging in I tried the same in virtual console this is working fine there. I tried debugging the same and with the help from google found that 'xev' is returning wrong keycode after logging in with user.

Please find below the 'xev' output after logging in with user.
on pressing character 'o'

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x4a6, subw 0x0, time 616901, (137,117), root:(934,169),
    state 0x10, keycode 85 (keysym 0xffb6, KP_6), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (36) "6"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (36) "6"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x4a6, subw 0x0, time 616997, (137,117), root:(934,169),
    state 0x10, keycode 85 (keysym 0xffb6, KP_6), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (36) "6"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

'xev' output after logging in with guest.
 on pressing character 'o'

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x4a6, subw 0x0, time 364101, (90,118), root:(887,170),
    state 0x0, keycode 32 (keysym 0x6f, o), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x4a6, subw 0x0, time 364183, (90,118), root:(887,170),
    state 0x0, keycode 32 (keysym 0x6f, o), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This was working fine earlier. I m trying to figure out which process after logging in with user is changing the key map.

Comment: You have a laptop and NUM LOCK, that's all.

Comment: And to think that some one would have gotten hurt because of `NUM LOCK` :)

Comment: Yes it really was a bad day for me :)